# Boolean Comparison - Prolog

Tags: prolog

I proggramm in java and c and I am new in prolog.

How can I know if a boolean expression is true or false?

```
 has_pellet([[Xpellet,Ypellet]|_], Xpacman, Ypacman):- Xpacman = Xpellet, Ypacman = Ypellet, !.
 has_pellet([_|Restpellets], Xpacman, Ypacman):- has_pellet(Restpellets,Xpacman,Ypacman).
```

Example:

The result of this command is false and I don't understand why, because `has_pellet([[1,2]],1,2)` is true. How can I verify this?

```
 has_pellet([[1,2]],1,2)==true.
```

Thanks.

Comment: You just enter `has_pellet([[1,2]],1,2).` at the prolog prompt to query. If it is true, then prolog will response either "true" (yes). Otherwise "false" (no). I just tried it with your logic and it came back "true".

Comment: But if I want to use this verification in other function how can I do it?

Comment: You do it the same way. You just query. So if you have a predicate that you want to be true only if `P1`, `P2`, and `P3` are true, then you would say, `my_predicate :- P1, P2, P3`. In this case `has_pellet([[1,2]],1,2)` represents one of the `Pi` expressions. Perhaps it would help if you gave a more detailed example in your problem statement what you are trying to do?